# Managing UX technical debt in a new application

Tags: web-app, design

I am an SQA working on a new Learning Management System, that will launch in the next month. I think the system is very ugly and has bad UX.

We are using JSF and Prime Faces and my team does not have a designer or usability expert. The developer is the one prototyping and developing the screens.

When I suggested modifications to improve the UX, the response was:

> First we'll make it work, and we'll make it beautiful later

I think this is very problematic because we'll have other things to worry about in the future. We increase the UX [technical debt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technical_debt), and that worries me.

My question is: How can we decrease our UX technical debt and make this system better?